# Why do I need to retain the result of NSDateFormatter dateFromString:

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, retain

I have an NSDate* that I'm storing as a property with the retain keyword:

`@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate* startTime;`

I use it as follows:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];
startTime = (NSDate*)[[NSUserDefaults] standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"StartTimeKey"];
if (startTime == nil)
  startTime = [[dateFormatter dateFromString:@"8:00 am"] retain];
```

Why do I need to retain the result of the `dateFromString:` message, but I don't need to retain the result of `objectForKey:` ?

I just upgraded to XCode 4.2 and I'm now using the LLVM GCC 4.2 compiler.  Before the upgrade, the code worked fine without the retain.  Now it crashes (later in the code when I access the startDate property) without the retain message.

Comment: By the rules, you should not have to retain it because dateFromString will autorelease but the startTime property should retain on assignment since it's attributed to retain

Comment: BTW, looks like dataFormatter leaks (if you're not using ARC).

Comment: @DavidDunham - I think it's standardUserDefaults objectForKey: that leaks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you wrote this:

```
startTime = blah blah blah;
```

You're setting the instance variable `startTime` directly.  If you do this instead:

```
self.startTime = blah blah blah;
```

then the compiler will turn it into this:

```
[self setStartTime:blah blah blah];
```

and the automatically-generated setter method will do the retain for you.

If you do this:

```
@synthesize startTime = _startTime;
```

then the instance variable will be named `_startTime`, making it easier to remember to use the property instead of assigning to the instance variable directly.

Comment: +1 - by the way, this is why I like differentiating between the iVar and the property with something like _startTime for the iVar.  Then it's really clear when you're going directly to the iVar.

Comment: @rob - thanks for clarifying.  I was working on the wrong assumption that `startTime` was synonymous with and a shortcut for `self.startTime`  Now I see that they do refer to the same object, but when accessing the property with `self.startTime` XCode will add magic hidden code to do the retain.

Comment: Still unclear on why standardUserDefaults objectForKey: seems to add an extra retain count in the above code.

Comment: standardUserDefaults isn't adding a retain for you to use.  It presumably keeps the value in its own private dictionary, so it retains the value for longer than you're using it.  On the other hand, dateFormatter is creating a new NSDate and autoreleasing it, so if you don't retain it, it goes away in the next pass through the run loop.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the Memory Management Programming Guide on page 11.

You own an object you create (that is you do not need to retain it, it has been done ).  You create an object with alloc, new, copy or mutablecopy.

In this case, the dateFormatter gives you a new object but, since you did not call alloc, new or copy yourself, dateFormatter will call (normally its how it works) autorealease on the new NSDAte object.

But, if you were setting your property using the setter and getter, you would no have this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  As I mentioned in my comment to @rob's answer, I thought I was setting the property, and did not realize I was actually giving a value to the iVar, therefore bypassing the setter.